# Can not uninstall standard Android keyboard or get it back working

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, adb, shell

I want to uninstall the standard Android keyboard `com.android.inputmethod.latin`.
I googled and found multiple [threads discussing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755739/how-to-delete-an-app-from-adb-without-knowing-its-package-name) this problem.

What I did so far:

1.) Uninstall via intent -> doesn't work

2.) `adb uninstall com.android.inputmethod.latin`

3.) `adb uninstall -k com.android.inputmethod.latin`

4.) My phone is rooted: `adb root`, `adb shell`, `pm uninstall -k com.android.inputmethod.latin`

But non of these methods worked yet. The AOSP Keyboard is still for selection in the android settings and the package is still shown when executing `pm list packages | grep latin`

The problem is: my keyboard isn't working any more :D
So can i reinstall or uninstall it?

Please help me!

Comment: Is it possible it will not uninstall because it leaves you with none? Maybe load an alternate keyboard first, for failover to occur, freeing the latin keyboard for removal?

Comment: I managed to install the softkeyboard. Stil, can't uninstall or reinstall it

Answer (score -1):

Maybe  you can remove manually using adb shell.

`adb remount` 
 
`adb shell`
 
`adb su` 
`cd system` 
 
`cd app` 
`rm yourapkname.apk` -> Change to the apk you want to remove 
`reboot`